# Find and replace with sample from a list

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataframe called 'out' with the following strings in it.

```
out<-data.frame(c("Normal","Normal","Abnormal","Normal","Abnormal","Abnormal","Normal","Abnormal"))
```

I want to replace the "Normal" with a string sampled from a list as follows

```
mychoices<-(x="Really bad",x="so so", x="Actually OK")
```

I have tried:

```
str_replace_all(out[,1],"Normal", as.character(sample(mychoices,1,replace=F)))
```

but it only replaces with one of the list throughout. I tried wrapping it in a function as well

```
out2 <- apply(out, 1, function(x) {
  if (stringr::str_detect(x, "Normal")) {
    return(str_replace_all(out[,1],"Normal", as.character(sample(mychoices,1,replace=F))))
  }
})
```

But it returns lists within a dataframe.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is one way of doing what I think you want. I changed your data structure a little to make it easier to work with (gave the column a name, and set `stringsAsFactors = FALSE`)

```
out <- data.frame(abornorm = c("Normal","Normal","Abnormal","Normal","Abnormal","Abnormal","Normal","Abnormal"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

out$abornorm[out$abornorm == "Normal"] <- sample(c("Really bad", "so so", "Actually OK"), sum(out$abornorm == "Normal", na.rm = TRUE), replace = TRUE)
```

This takes advantage of the ability to assign a set of indices of a vector, provided your source and target are of the same length.